# how to sum two columns from different tables

Tags: mysql

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['username']); 
$qry="(SELECT SUM(amount) from deposits) + (SELECT SUM(amount) from referral) as value_sum WHERE username ='$username' ";
```

I have tried to use this but I keep getting this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '+ (SELECT SUM(amount) from referral) as value_sum WHERE username ='test0'' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You create two queries and use UNION to add the results to each other:

```
SELECT SUM(value_sum)
  FROM ( 
         SELECT SUM(amount) as value_sum
           FROM deposits AS D
          WHERE username = '$username'
         UNION
         SELECT SUM(amount) as value_sum
           FROM referral AS R
          WHERE username = '$username'
       ) AS U
```

Comment: Your code doesn't sum it up.

Comment: You were right. Edited the code to sum up the two rows returned by the union clause.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: It does here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba2d8a/1)

Comment: You might have to adjust the WHERE clause, specifically that the $username gets replaced properly (which is of course not the case in my sqlfiddle).